# How can I define the cursor position in a AutoHotKey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote a **AutoHotKey** script to print out these four lines:

```
==quote
web

12
```

but I want the **cursor** to be blinking between the line "web" and the line "12", I would think I could include the word "Cursor" like this:

```
::qqu::==quote{Enter}{Cursor}{Enter}web{Enter}12
```

but it just leaves the cursor at the end of the "12".

**How can I define the ending cursor position?**

Comment: Send the up arrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `{Left}{Left}{Left}` after everything. This should move cursor back to proper location.

Comment: ok, by trial and error and I get the cursor to move up to the place I want, but e.g. putting {Up}{Up}{Left}{Left} in at the end moves the cursor into the right line but it is at the second cursor (won't move left), and in NotePad it goes up into the first line and splits up the word "quote" between the "u" and the "o", so this method seems to be pretty hit and miss, and when I get it write, if I add a paragraph of text, I need to add dozens of {left}, there must be a way just to tell it where to put the cursor when its done, isn't there?

Comment: I haven't used this facility of AutoHotkey, but looking at the other keys you guys are showing, I'd try {Home} to get to the left margin, then {Up} to the row I want.

Comment: hmmm, for such a well-thought out tool I would think it would have something more absolute-positioning than this turtle-graphic approach to getting the cursor where you want after the script finishes

Answer (score 13):

Just a note:

Send {Left}{Left}{Left}

is the equivalent of...

Send {Left 3}